# Why there huge difference in two RSA methods(.NET RSA and wiki RSA)?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am currently implementing RSA. I am using it to encrypt id. And id is mostly like this. e.g. A1234, A1265, B1234, B2345(in id first character is either A or B and remaing are numbers).

I am implenting RSA described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation) link.

What I am doing is first replacing A to 1 and B to 2 then convert it to long and then do encryption and decryption as below.

```
private long Encr(string id)
{
    long y = Convert.ToInt64(id.Replace("A", "1").Replace("B", "2"));
    return power2(y, e, mod); // e is public key which is number(long)
}

private string Decr(long y)
{
    var x= power2(y, d, mod).ToString();  // d is private key which is number(long)
    if (x.Substring(0, 1) == "1")
        return "A" + x.Substring(1);
    if (x.Substring(0, 1) == "2")
        return "B" + x.Substring(1);
    return "null";
}

private long power2(long x, long y, long n)
{
    long temp = 1;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        var z = y & 1;
        if (z == 1)
        {
            temp = ((temp % n) * (x % n)) % n;
        }

        x = ((x % n) * (x % n)) % n;

        y = y >> 1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And I also used RSA provided by .NET. I am surprised by the results of both methods(one that I have Implemented and one that .NET provide). 
Results are something like this.

```
id      |     My Method                        |    .NET RSA
--------|--------------------------------------|-------------
A1234   |Encryption:-time=0.0000017 s          |Encryption:- time=0.0001047 s
        |            value=56485               |             value=0aR+BrYbO8eMFaQQz12QMw==
        |Decryption:-time=0.0000117 s          |Decryption:- time=0.0001132 s
        |            value=11234               |             value=A1234
```

I don't why there is huge difference in this two. **Is there I am doing something wrong in my method.(Is there any loophole in my method)?**

I want fast encryption-decryption method. So what I have implemented is right or there is chance of collision in my method. Or I have to use some other method for encryption and decryption which is very much fast.

Comment: From your methods output you have either made a typo or its not working

Comment: Note that the system libraries are probably using padding. "Schoolbook" RSA like the description on Wikipedia  is **completely insecure**.

Comment: In order to compare you need to show the .NET RSA code you've timed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot program RSA for any meaningful key size using direct `long` calculations. RSA works for key sizes of about 1024 bits or higher. Anything lower than 512 is *trivially broken* and your RSA only handles key sizes of 64 bit *if you're lucky*.

So the .NET implementation will use `BigInteger` values. It will likely also provide protection against side channel attacks. And to be secure it should perform correct padding as well - although looking at the output it currently does not.

So yes, it is slower. But then again, it provides a *meaningful* implementation of RSA, which you do not (except for providing a learning experience, of course).

Comment: I'm saying *direct `long`* calculations as you can use long to implement BigInteger. Obviously a generic CPU can do any possible calculation - you could do RSA 8192 bit calculations using an 8 bit CPU, albeit *extremely slowly*.

Comment: As describe here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation, I took one e(public key),d(one private key) and derived other attribute and as long as my id not cross n(which is let say 9999999999) I get unique value every time for encryption(for different ids).So is there any chance that what I implemented was wrong?

Comment: Define wrong. It will probably adhere to the RSA problem if implemented correctly. It can be trivially decrypted as factorization would be very easy to do. The RSA problem is computationally hard, but for that to have any effect the primes p and q should be about 512 bits or higher. Solving Sudoku's is also computationally hard (maybe you didn't expect that) but my Sudoku solver solves *any* 9x9 sudoku in .2 seconds, and that's just the startup time of the Java virtual machine. The Sudoku must have larger dimensions for it to be hard to solve.

Comment: Or stated differently: cryptography can be used to help secure a system; that an application functions tells us nothing about the security provided. That the output looks random doesn't tell us anything either. The Mersenne twister random number generator outputs pseudo random values, but it is not cryptographically secure.